# Oracle SQL Developer Data Import Wizard Timestamp Format for string like "2022-12-14 20:48:45.596206"

Tags: oracle, csv, import

I'm trying to import some csv files into Oracle Database. The import wizard can't recognize timestamp like this: "2022-12-14 20:48:45.596206". I found some answer that only has millisecond, but here it contains microsecond..What should I type in the Format for Data Import Wizard to recognize this kind of timestamp correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Nvm. I missed the "." between second and microsecond. It should be YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.ff6